# How to display Object as complex html table in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have below object that I want to display as per below template. Can anyone please guide me in this? I want it to be optimized simple and quick.

Thanks in Advance.

**Object:**

```
var dataSource =  [
    {
        Id: 5,
        CriteriaName: 'First Criteria',
        CustomerName: 'Customer-1',
        Points: 350, Total: 500
    },
    {
        Id: 5,
        CriteriaName: 'First Criteria',
        CustomerName: 'Customer-2',
        Points: 250,
        Total: 500
    },
    {
        Id: 5,
        CriteriaName: 'First Criteria',
        CustomerName: 'Customer-3',
        Points:150,
        Total: 500
    },
    {
        Id: 5,
        CriteriaName: 'Second Criteria',
        CustomerName: 'Customer-1',
        Points:400,
        Total: 450
    },
    {
        Id: 5,
        CriteriaName: 'Second Criteria',
        CustomerName: 'Customer-2',
        Points: 300,
        Total: 450
    },
    {
        Id: 5,
        CriteriaName: 'Second Criteria',
        CustomerName: 'Customer-3',
        Points:200,
        Total: 450
    }
];
```

And desired output would be:

[image]

**jsfiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/7L79dryr/1/

Comment: so the header is static always 4 heards is it ? (total , cutomer-1 ,  cutomer-2 ,  cutomer-3 ) ?

Comment: no it will be distinct CustomerName, and Total

Comment: It seems need to group by **CriteriaName**.

Comment: please consider we will have customerid too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to map this to a different data structure as well as an array of customers

```
 <table class='tbl'>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th>total</th>
       <th ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer}}</th>          
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat='(name, data) in criteria'>
       <td>{{name}}</td>
       <td>{{data.Total}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="customer in customers">
           {{data[customer] ? data[customer]  : 'N/A' }}
       </td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

JS

```
var customers = {},
    criteria = {};

data.forEach(function(item){
   customers[item.CustomerName]=true;
   if(!criteria[item.CriteriaName]){   
      criteria[item.CriteriaName]= {Total:item.Total}
   }
   criteria[item.CriteriaName][item.CustomerName]  = item.Points;
});

$scope.customers = Object.keys(customers).sort();
$scope.criteria = criteria;
```

Not sure how the `Total` should work , I just used the first available one

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7L79dryr/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: doesn't work for me, cause I also want to post data to the server

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: object doest have TotalPoints column

Comment: I answered what was asked in question and also provided a demo that matched expected display results. if there is more then question needs to have more details added to it. Otherwise you should accept this and modify it to your needs